# Get multiple values to php via ajax created dynamically by javascript

Tags: arrays

Im generating addition fields on a form by javascript dyanamically and each row contains three fields so i want to be able to post all the values in all the fields displayed to php using ajax

am able to generate the additional fields dynamically and post to php but only one colums is being sent.

+Here is the form

```
<table id="nameBoxWrap">
    <tr id="nameBox">
    <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber[]"  placeholder="phone number">
    <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname[]' placeholder='firstname'>
    <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname[]'  placeholder='lastname'>
    <input type="button" value="Load More" onclick="addNameSection()" >
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitdata1"  style="margin-left:50px"><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="addSectionCount" value="1" name="addSectionCount">

    </tr>
</table>
```

+here the code that generate other fields dyanamically

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addNameSection(){
    var addSectionCount=$("#addSectionCount").val();
    addSectionCount++;
    $("#addSectionCount").val(addSectionCount);
    $("#nameBoxWrap").append('<tr id="nameBox'+addSectionCount+'"><td></td>'
        +'<td><input type="text" placeholder="phone number" id="phonenumber'+addSectionCount+'" name="phonenumber[]"></td>'
        +'<td><input type="text" id="firstname'+addSectionCount+'" name="firstname[]"  placeholder="firstname"></td>'
        +'<td><input type="text" id="lastname'+addSectionCount+'" name="lastname[]"  placeholder="lastname"><td>'
        +'<td><input type="button" value="REMOVE" onclick=removeNameSection("'+addSectionCount+'")></td></tr>');
}
</script>
```

+script that manage form data submission to database

```
<script>


    $(function(){
        $('#submitdata1').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  // do not allow the default form action
            var phoneS = $('input[name="phonenumber[]"]').serializeArray();
           var firstn = $('input[name="firstname[]"]').serializeArray();
          var lastname = $('input[name="lastname[]"]').serializeArray();

              $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "senddata.php",
                data:lastname 
                     });

        });
    });

    </script>
```

+here is my php script

```
    foreach($_POST['lastname'] as $key=>$value){
            $phone = $_POST['phonenumber'][$key];
          $lastname = $value;
          $firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$key];
          $query =mysqli_query($db,"insert into itequipment(phone_number,firstname,lastname) values ('$phone','$firstname','$lastname')");  

    }
```

+I want to store firstname,lastname,phonenumber in a row of database table but am only able to send and store lastname only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
$('#submitdata1').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // do not allow the default form action
  
  var list = {};
  var i = 0;
  
   $( "tr" ).each(function() {
     var inputs = $(this).find('input');
     list[i] = {};

      inputs.each(function() {
        $input = $(this);
        list[i][$input.attr('name')] = $input.val();
      });

      i++;
  });

  var json_data = JSON.stringify(list);
  var json = JSON.parse(json_data);  
  
  $.ajax({
      url : 'senddata.php.php',
      type : 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
      data : json
  });
   
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="line"> <!-- Line 1 -->
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='phonenumber' value="phone_1">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name='firstname' value="firstname_1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='lastname' value="lastname_1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="line"> <!-- Line 2 -->
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='phonenumber' value="phone_2">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name='firstname' value="firstname_2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='lastname' value="lastname_2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Result of** `console.log(json)` :

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}}

0:
firstname: "firstname_1"
lastname: "lastname_1"
phonenumber: "phonenumber_1"

1:
firstname: "firstname_2"
lastname: "lastname_2"
phonenumber: "phonenumber_2"
```

Comment: I tried the code but i cant get it to work, because am not getting anything on my php script is it possible for you to add php script that can store the values to database table @Harvey

Comment: @Pamzey Do you have anything in the json variable before sending Ajax ? You should have a similar result to my console.log

Comment: yes am getting that but i dont know how to retrieve then when sent to php. please help me am stuck i cant proceed with my project.

Comment: i got it working THANKS SO MUCH I REALLY APPRCIATE FOR YOUR HELP YOUR THE BEST!!!!!!

Comment: @Pamzey With pleasure, can you mark my solution as "correct" ?
Thank you